# reduce image size using imagemagick for batch of images

Tags: batch-file, imagemagick

I need to convert batch of .jpg images filesize using image magick. am able to convert a single file using the following code

```
  convert -strip -interlace Plane -gaussian-blur 0.05 -quality 65% 1.jpg result.jpg
```

I need to do this convert for a batch of images. i tried this but it is not working

```
   mogrify -path \images-rep  -strip -interlace Plane -gaussian-blur 0.05 -quality 66% *.jpg
```

Comment: try to double the percentage symbol

Comment: What does "it is not working" mean?

Comment: File size is not reducing

Comment: When i used double    (mogrify -path \images-rep  -strip -interlace Plane -gaussian-blur 0.05 -quality 66%% *.jpg) also not working

Comment: Is there any other way to reduce image size using mogrify

Comment: i referred this link, may i know what is \R in the for loop in the  http://nw2.us/wordpress/batch-compress-jpeg-with-imagemagick-windows/

Comment: According to [ImageMagick Command-line Options](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality) documentation about option **-quality** just the percentage value should be specified without percentage sign. Compare in this documentation `value` versus `value{%}`. So try just `-quality 65`

Comment: I've tried with/without/doubled `%`, and everything works. So, sorry, just a silly question, what folder are you looking for file size?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use this command to convert your batch of images under a folder

```
   mogrify -path imagepath  -strip -quality 50% *.jpg
```

Comment: this renames the files too, which means it does not preserve image name.

Answer (score 3):

To specify a maximum file size, `mogrify -define jpeg:extent=300kb *.jpg`. However, this can be *much* slower than just `-quality 50%` and/or `-resize 50%`.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/11920384/2097284

Answer (score 2):

Reduce the depth of the image  will reduce the size of the image

```
-depth 5
```