# JPG and PNG compression, PHP and Ubunutu with jpegtran and pngcrush

Tags: jpeg, image-compression, image-optimization, pngcrush, jpegtran

I have several hundred images I need to optimise and compress. I have found the following script on github: https://gist.github.com/ryansully/1720244 which works ok. However the filesizes of the jpgs are not much smaller after compression.

For example, one file before compression is `870.24 KB`, after it is `724.97 KB`. But, if I run the same image through [compressjpg.com](http://www.compressjpg.com) it reduces the filesize to around `290 KB`.

How can I achieve this level of compression with jpegtran? Is it even possible?

Comment: Why not use ImageMagick and get whatever output size you want? What are you trying to achieve overall - disk is really cheap....

Comment: @MarkSetchell. I've already used Imagick to resize images so got that covered. I was more interested in removing EXIF data etc to reduce filesize even further. Basically whatever they are doing at compressjpg.com

Comment: `mogrify -strip *.jpg` will remove EXIF data - try it on a copy of your files first. You can also specify the desired output filesize if you want to.

Comment: Regarding setting the output filesize:  `convert original.jpeg -define jpeg:extent=300kb output.jpg` [from this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917219/imagemagick-scale-jpeg-image-with-a-maximum-file-size)