# With ImageMagick, how can a JPEG image be reduced in quality until it is below a certain file size?

Tags: imagemagick

A JPEG image can be reduced in quality and, thus, in file size using ImageMagick in a way such as the following:

```
convert -quality 85% image.jpg image_small.jpg
```

How can the quality of an image be reduced such that the resulting image is below a certain file size (e.g. 3 MB)? A scenario in which this would be useful would be preparing a large number of images for upload to a site like Imgur.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I thought there was a post about this last week but can not find it. There was another here: [ImageMagick: scale JPEG image with a maximum file-size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917219/imagemagick-scale-jpeg-image-with-a-maximum-file-size)

Anyway you want to use: -define jpeg:extent=400KB https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#define

Out of interest your code is wrong as the input comes after convert and your quality goes before the output image.

So you want something like this:

```
convert image.jpg -define jpeg:extent=3000KB image_small.jpg
```

If you have an old version of Imagemagick it may not work that is why it is always good to include your imagemagick version in your question.
The results are a bit hit and miss on exact filesize.