# Compressing image but keeping same dimensions with Imagemagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick

I have a model handling images uploadeded with *paperclip* and processed with *imagemagick*.

Here is the model code :

```
has_attached_file :image, styles: { big: "2000x2000", small: "1000x1000", thumb: "250x250"}
validates_attachment :image, content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png"] }
```

I use all those different styles but I also use the *original* style. Though the original size may be very big, some pictures are above 15 Mo.

I would like to compress the *original* style yet not knowing exactly what size it is, sometimes image is cropped and the 3:2 ratio is not respected.

I found this thread : [Reducing the file size of a very large images, without changing the image dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257322/reducing-the-file-size-of-a-very-large-images-without-changing-the-image-dimens) 
yet not adapted to Rails environment.